# Freezed Expired Bread

Tags: bread, storage, pastry

So I'm an expatriate at a totally new place, and all bread sold in here got 2~4 days expiry and I usually don't finish it in that short period of time, I always store all kinds of breads and pastry/bakery in the freezer, and get them out before using by few hours, then get the rest back to the freezer. 
So I was wondering is it safe to eat an expired bread? The color and smell of the bread never changed at all.

If it might make any difference, the type of bread I'm referring to is pita bread.

Comment: If I put a sticker on my breads to "make them expire the next day", i will be pretty sure nobody is *somehow* getting sick eating my bread. And paranoid people buy new breads every day, throwing the still good but unfinished breads in the bin.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yea I read the mentioned answer thank you. I was just asking specifically for the expiration date thing as I was worried about it, and I'm still not sure of an answer to my question. So to answer yours, not yet.